# Serverless-aws-documentation swagger parameters

Tags: serverless

When I use `serverless openapi generate` the resulting `openapi.yaml` contains no parameters

I have tried parameters instead queryParams as well as pathParams

```
functions:
  get:
    handler: retransmit/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: retransmit/{game_id}/{camera_id}
          method: get
          cors: true
          documentation:
            summary: "Fetch frame_id"
            description: "Fetch frame_id ranges for given grab_id and camera_id"
            queryParams:
              - name: "game_id"
                description: "app id"
                required: true
              - name: "camera_id"
                description: "user id or 'my'"
                required: true
```

error:

```
Semantic error at paths./retransmit/{game_id}/{camera_id}
Declared path parameter "game_id" needs to be defined as a path parameter at either the path or operation level
Jump to line 27
Semantic error at paths./retransmit/{game_id}/{camera_id}
Declared path parameter "camera_id" needs to be defined as a path parameter at either the path or operation level
Jump to line 27
```

Comment: I would expect that  the resulting file is called `openapi.yaml`.

Comment: @Anthon correct, my mistake

Comment: Did you have any luck, @Max0999? I'm struggling with this issue myself and the docs don't seem to help 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **queryParams** to **pathParams**

```
functions:
  get:
    handler: retransmit/get.get
    events:
      - http:
          path: retransmit/{game_id}/{camera_id}
          method: get
          cors: true
          documentation:
            summary: "Fetch frame_id"
            description: "Fetch frame_id ranges for given grab_id and camera_id"
            pathParams:
              - name: "game_id"
                description: "app id"
                required: true
              - name: "camera_id"
                description: "user id or 'my'"
                required: true
```